# Make objects in session immutable in Java

Tags: java, immutability

In a web based application we have an `User` object in the `session` for each logged in user.

The user is as below

```
Class User {
    //With setter and getters
      private String userId,
      private String name,
      private Account Account,
 }

Class Account {
     //with setter and getters.
     private String accountNumber;    
 }
```

When the user logged in a session object is created for him and his `userId` ,`name` and `Account` will be set for him.

After that, every programmer can access the `session` and read user and his information. But it is possible that one programmer change the `Account` by mistake.

For example:

```
 1. TrasnferVO = new TransferVO;
 2. TransferVO.setAccount( user.getAccount() );
 3. TransferVO.getAccount.setAccountNumber("foo");
 4. User user = getUserFromSession();
 5. user.getAccountNumber(); // Now I have foo
```

At line **2** a new **copy** of user account should be created and set to `TransferVO` because the the object reference is passed not its value! 
So the line **3** will change the user session account number. And we will lost the corrupted `accountNumber` in session.

Is there any guideline to handle it or every individual programmer must take care of it.

Of course this mistake can happen in every code in the project, but I am looking for a way to make the session object properties, which is very important, immutable.

Comment: Use the inmmutable pattern, do not create setter methods for the object that shouldn't be modified, and extend your API to be able to create instance/copies of the inmmutable object that may be altered

Comment: I don't get it. What prevents you from making all those fields final; so that they are setup exactly once? I really don't get the question. Of course one should make sure that objects that aren't supposed to change ... do not offer means to change their content upon creation.

Comment: @Jägermeister Do you mean make the `User.AccountVO` final ?! I can't because blank final field should be initialized. The `AccountVO` changes for each user

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi Are we really supposed to understand what is `User.AccounVO`?

Comment: Just create a DTO for the purpose.

Comment: Dear @BalusC I agreed that it is not a JSP, servlets and session problem. And I tried to explain the situation which happens in my project. I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The situation in your Question is not clear.

## Make object immutable

To make an [immutable object in Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Java), you have two ways:

- Encapsulation: mark the members as `private`, define an interface with no setter methods, and implement that interface on your class. Pass the object as an instance of that read-only interface to your session.
- Mark the members as `final`. The members can be assigned a reference to an object (or primitive value) only once. Members marked `final` cannot be re-assigned.

Remember that in either case above the object assigned to the member may itself be modifiable. Assigning an object to the member of your class is what we are protecting in both cases above, but modifying that assigned object’s own internal members is a separate issue.

## Copy the object

Or you can make a copy of an object, then proceed with your modifications on the clone. Perhaps this best suits your situation.

Learn about the marker interface [`Cloneable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) and about overriding the `protected`  [`Object::clone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--) method with a `public` one. Read:

- [How do I copy an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/869033/642706)
- [Object Copying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#In_Java)